# AuthController in another module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I use Authentication in zf2 in:

This is a controller

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Admin\Model\User;

class AuthController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $form;
    protected $storage;
    protected $authservice;

    public function getAuthService() {
        if (!$this->authservice) {
            $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService');
        }

        return $this->authservice;
    }

    public function getSessionStorage() {
        if (!$this->storage) {
            $this->storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\Model\MyAuthStorage');
        }

        return $this->storage;
    }

    public function getForm() {
        if (!$this->form) {
            $user = new User();
            $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
            $this->form = $builder->createForm($user);
        }

        return $this->form;
    }

    public function loginAction() {
        //if already login, redirect to success page 
        if ($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('success');
        }

        $form = $this->getForm();

        return array(
            'form' => $form,
            'messages' => $this->flashmessenger()->getMessages()
        );
    }

    public function authenticateAction() {
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $redirect = 'login';

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                //check authentication...
                $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
                        ->setIdentity($request->getPost('username'))
                        ->setCredential($request->getPost('password'));

                $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
                foreach ($result->getMessages() as $message) {
                    //save message temporary into flashmessenger
                    $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage($message);
                }

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    $redirect = 'success';
                    //check if it has rememberMe :
                    if ($request->getPost('rememberme') == 1) {
                        $this->getSessionStorage()
                                ->setRememberMe(1);
                        //set storage again
                        $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());
                    }
                    $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());
                    $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($request->getPost('username'));
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect);
    }

    public function logoutAction() {
        if ($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->getSessionStorage()->forgetMe();
            $this->getAuthService()->clearIdentity();
            $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage("Logout done.");
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
    }

}
```

When i try to use this controller in another module "Posts for example" it return an error message:

Using

```
use Admin\Controller\AuthController;

public function indexAction() {

    $getAuth = new AuthController();

    $getAuth->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity();

    $authService = $getAuth->getAuthService();
    if ( $authService->hasIdentity() ) {
        echo 'Auth area';
    }
}
```

The error message return is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   .....\Controller\PostsController.php on line 31
>
> Line 31 mean:
>   $getAuth->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity();

What is the problem ?!

Comment: Using `getServiceLocator()` in your controllers is terrible practice. Don't do this. Inject the dependancies into your controller, don't get them from the service manager from within the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Service locator is not injected in your `AuthController` so you don't get it calling `getServiceLocator()` function on `$getAuth` object which causes that `get()` function to not work.

Use `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity();`

As Tomdarkness said its bad practice, just wanted to show you here how you should fix your code and what`s bad.

Check out this link [getting dependencies into zf2 controllers](http://www.zfdaily.com/2012/07/getting-dependencies-into-zf2-controllers/) how you can do constructor injection of your service locator.

Comment: While this would likely solve the problem, using `$this->getServiceLocator()` within your controllers is bad practice. Inject the dependancies into the controller.